# Converting a string to UTF-8 in ruby

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I'm getting this output:

> Don\u0092t

unicode character 92 is the right character, but why isn't is it displaying? This string is being read from a file. The chardet output for the file is:

> ISO-8859-2 with confidence 0.795656700854

This is how I am opening the file:

```
File.open('file.txt', 'r:ISO-8859-2')
```

Then, with a given line of the file I output it like this:

```
puts line.encode('UTF-8')
```

Comment: Getting that output how? Please provide your code. Also, ISO-8859-2 would mean that the text is *not* UTF-8.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall made some edits to address your two questions (or question and statement) thanks!

Comment: @quinn try to use `force_encoding('utf-8')` instead.

Comment: @kugaevsky force_encoding didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed the file open statement to use: 'r:windows-1252:utf-8'. I guess chardet just didn't detect the encoding correctly.

Comment: Yep that seemed to fix it.. I wonder is there any way I could've fixed this without lucky guessing?

Comment: "I guess chardet just didn't detect the encoding correctly." Chardet's value is a probability of being correct. The ISO-8859-n set is closely related, and, unless the text being sampled has all characters in the set, chardet will have to guess what is in the gaps, and often will guess wrong. This is a maddening thing. There are lots of reasons this happens, but it's the wonderfulness of dealing with multiple character sets on the internet.

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan and so does this mean that chardet is the best tool out there for this beyond finding the original author of the file and getting them to tell me the encoding?

Comment: That's been my experience. If you study the ISO-8859-n sets and Win-1252 you'll learn which character slots are different, and can write some code to search for only those alternate characters. You'll still find that in an "english" document many different sets could match and it'll take the accented characters to help you differentiate between the sets. It's all about your sample size. And, in a sufficiently large document, quoting different languages, you could still find characters outside your proposed character set which will throw everything off. UTF-8 helps but it's not universal.